# Postgres 9.4.5 Upgrade to 9.5

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have a Postgres (version **9.4.5**) database running on CentOS 6.7.

How would I be able to upgrade my current Postgres distribution to **v9.5.x**?

This must be done with minimal damage to the data as well as minimum down time as this server is currently in production.

I have considered installing a separate instance of Postgres 9.5 and swapping the balancer to point to the new instance. Then in the background perform sequential inserts. However this would cause problems with serialized columns. It is definitely not the ideal scenario.

For anyone curious, this change is being done because Postgres 9.4.5 does not have a method to perform an upsert without potential data loss and/or concurrency errors.

It should be noted that the database is currently **300GB** in size and is mainly used for data warehousing.

The hardware specifications are:

CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz

RAM: **128GB**

STORAGE: **1.5TB PCIE SSD**

Comment: pg_upgrade:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html.  Obviously you want to have a copy for prod, do the backup on the other, and then swap it back.  I'd ask this on server exchange because they can give you better details on how to do this with minimal downtime and minimal data loss.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Generally speaking what you said works, the problem is getting those better details to avoid or minimize the data loss as much as possible.

Comment: how much downtime can you afford for the upgrade?

Comment: If at all possible, none. But considering the impracticality of that - we may be able to afford up to 30 minutes of downtime since that could be performed during regularly scheduled maintenance.